# splitdexfile causes crash : Facebook SDK Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object

Tags: android, facebook, proguard, dexguard

I tried to apply `splitdexfile` option to split Facebook's sdk as a separate dex file.

What I've done so far:

**1)** I've added below line to my `dexguard-project.txt` file:

```
-splitdexfile com.facebook.**
```

**2)** And below line to my `project.properties` file:

```
proguard.config=dexguard-project.txt
```

**3)** I've exported a signed apk with `Export Optimized and Obfuscated Application Package... (DexGuard)` option successfully.

**4)** I checked and confirmed that the apk is splitted to 2 dex files:
[image]

Then I installed the apk to a device, and tried facebook connect and got;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = o.?$?)
```

I couldn't find the `o.?$?`class at generated `mapping.txt` file.

**DexGuard Version:** 6.1

**Facebook SDK Version:** 3.22.0

**Full Stacktrace:**

```
04-10 10:12:55.727: E/ActivityThread(15362): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.devrim/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = o.?$?)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = o.?$?)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2177)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2022)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1259)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:4543)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:65)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    ... 11 more
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: o.?$?
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2304)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1663)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1806)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2171)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    ... 20 more
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: o/?$?
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    ... 30 more
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "o.?$?" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.devrim-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.devrim-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-10 10:12:58.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15362):    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by adding below lines to `dexguard-project.txt` file:

```
-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable { *;}
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable { *;}
```

Comment: Did you compile a release version of your app after adding `-keep` and `-keepclassmembers` from your answer? Now I am struggling with the following problem. When I add `-keep class` for classes of a compile dependency, Dexguard doesn't split those classes, and the number of methods exceeds 65K. Thus, the project is not compiled. When I delete my `-keep class` lines, the project can be compiled.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev have you used multidex option? Also your problem is not very related to this question and the answer